# How it is possible to calculate only one eigenvector for one eigenvalue lambda=1 on C++ as efficiently as possible

Tags: lapack, intel-mkl, eigenvalue, eigenvector

С++ have a very efficient algorithm to calculate eigenvalues and eigenvectors in MKL library with function dgeev. But it calculates all Eigenvalues, and all left and rirhgt eigenvectors.

[DGEEV Example Program Results](https://software.intel.com/sites/products/documentation/doclib/mkl_sa/11/mkl_lapack_examples/dgeev_ex.c.htm)

> Eigenvalues  (  2.86, 10.76) (  2.86,-10.76) ( -0.69,  4.70) ( -0.69,
>   -4.70) -10.46
>
> Left eigenvectors  (  0.04,  0.29) (  0.04, -0.29) ( -0.13, -0.33) (
>   -0.13,  0.33)   0.04  (  0.62,  0.00) (  0.62,  0.00) (  0.69,  0.00) (  0.69,  0.00)   0.56  ( -0.04, -0.58) ( -0.04,  0.58) ( -0.39,
>   -0.07) ( -0.39,  0.07)  -0.13  (  0.28,  0.01) (  0.28, -0.01) ( -0.02, -0.19) ( -0.02,  0.19)  -0.80  ( -0.04,  0.34) ( -0.04, -0.34) ( -0.40,  0.22) ( -0.40, -0.22)   0.18
>
> Right eigenvectors  (  0.11,  0.17) (  0.11, -0.17) (  0.73,  0.00) (
>   0.73,  0.00)   0.46  (  0.41, -0.26) (  0.41,  0.26) ( -0.03, -0.02) ( -0.03,  0.02)   0.34  (  0.10, -0.51) (  0.10,  0.51) (  0.19, -0.29) (  0.19,  0.29)   0.31  (  0.40, -0.09) (  0.40,  0.09) ( -0.08,
>   -0.08) ( -0.08,  0.08)  -0.74  (  0.54,  0.00) (  0.54,  0.00) ( -0.29, -0.49) ( -0.29,  0.49)   0.16

For large matrices it takes a lot of time. Especially if you need to calculate eigenvectors for a large number of matrices.

So the main question is how can I calculate the only one eigenvector for real matrix only for one eigenvalue lambda = 1 as fast as possible? 
Or how I can solve the system of linear equations A-E=0, where A is a real matrix, E - Identity matrix. 
The eigenvector 100% exist and it consists only real numbers.

Comment: This isn't really a C++ question.  It is algorithms that are used to find eigenvalues and eigenvectors, and algorithms are independent of programming language.    There are various algorithms to find the largest eigenvalue of a matrix, but the choice of algorithm depends on properties of the matrix.  For an example of relevant discussion, have a look at   https://scicomp.stackexchange.com/questions/1681/what-is-the-fastest-way-to-calculate-the-largest-eigenvalue-of-a-general-matrix

Comment: I know that my max eigenvalue = 1 for all matrix. There is no question, how I can find the eigenvalues. There is a question of how I can compute one eigenvector for eigenvalue = 1 with maximum performance. If found in Eigen library EigenSolver. And it consist doComputeEigenvectors(). But it complicated to extract this function.

Answer (score 0):

You can't really solve `B x = 0` with `B = A - I`. This equation has infinitely many solutions if `A` has a unit eigenvalue.

For the simplest solution, put `x(n) = 1` for arbitrary `n`, say `n = N`. Then use first `N-1` equations to find `x(1:N-1)`. Effectively, you'll have to solve `B' x' = r` for `x' = x(1:N-1)`, where `B' = B(1:N-1, 1:N-1)`, and `r = -B(1:N-1,N)`. This can easily be done using MKL/LAPACK `?gesv` routine specifying appropriate values for matrix sizes and leading dimensions.

Note that depending on `A`, `B'` can also be singular. Then you'll have to fix more `x_n` components. In the extreme case, when `A = I`, all `x_n`s are arbitrary.

Comment: ?gesv is not an optimal solution. I know that my max eigenvalue = 1 for all matrix. There is a question of how I can compute one eigenvector for eigenvalue = 1 with maximum performance. I found in Eigen library the EigenSolver() function. And it consist doComputeEigenvectors(). But it complicated to extract this function.